# WCF security TransportWithMessageCredentials with WsHttpBinding

Tags: .net, wcf, ws-security

I have my site ( https:// example.com). This is an internet app

> 1. User can register from the above site-- Completed
> 2. Register user will get a Email and will have a lick to download a Windows Client( WPF or Windows Form client) – Completed
> 3. This WPF or Windows form client will consume WCF( deployed in internet) which is hosted on example.com. I am internally passing UserName and Pwd in Message body.—Completed

Now what I need to know is how to implement Security at message level and transport level.

> 1. The Client request should be encrypted at message level
> 2. WCF server response should be encrypted at message level
> 3. Communication between Client and server should be SSL

I have gone through from `msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648902.aspx`

> 1. How to: Use wsHttpBinding with Username Authentication and TransportWithMessageCredentials in WCF Calling from Windows Forms
> 2. How to: Use Username Authentication with the SQL Server Membership Provider and Message Security in WCF Calling from Windows Forms
> 3. How to: Use Certificate Authentication and Message Security in WCF Calling from Windows Forms

After reading above I am confused which one I need to use.  Please suggest which one is the best option for my scenario to meet my above three security conditions

If I use `TransportWithMessageCredential`s do I  see encryption  at message level and transport level both?

Answer (score 0):

TransportWithMessageCredentials is an encryption/security option used when your WCF web service box is fronted by a load balancer, or reverse proxy, that is performing the SSL/HTTPs encyption work.

In a "normal" situation, where your WCF web service box lies within the logical DMZ, the encryption and client authentication check by the WCF host is done in a single step, and the "bare" request content (unencrypted and without client auth credentials) gets processed by your service.

However, if you've using a load balancer or reverse proxy that's performing the encryption (a good idea for many reasons), using "normal" transport encryption would deliver to your WCF web service a message WITHOUT the client authentication credentials.

So what TransportWithMessageCredentials does is it preserves, inside the message body, the client authentication credentials so that, after the RP/LB has decrypted your message, your WCF web service can in a second step process your client authentication request.

Follow? Basically, if you're using an F5 load balancer, or some reverse proxy, to encrypt/decrypt your messages before they're processed by WCF web service, you need TransportWithMessageCredentials. No load balancer or reverse proxy, no need for TransportWithMessageCredentials.

Hopefully that clarifies things.

Comment: Thanks for your response. please confirm .Is my understanding correct?

Comment: What I know is there are two security levels
1. Transport Security: Security is applied on a point-to-point basis, with no provision for multiple hops or routing through intermediate application nodes.

Comment: 2. Message Security: It provides end-to-end security. Because message security directly encrypts and signs the message, having intermediaries does not break the security. It allows partial or selective message encryption and signing, thus improving overall application performance
Thanks for your response. Please confirm .Is my understanding correct?   So with TransportWithMessageCredentials  we can achieve above two security that at transport level and Message Level( encrypted whole SOAP message ( Header, body ).

Comment: A third security mode uses both previous modes and brings advantages of both. This mode is called TransportWithMessageCredential. In this mode, message security is used to authenticate the client and transport security is used to authenticate the server and provide message confidentiality and integrity. Thanks to this, the TransportWithMessageCredential security mode is almost as fast as transport security mode and provides client authentication extensibility in the same way as message security. However, unlike message security mode, it does not provide complete end-to-end security.

Comment: As per https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms735093.aspx. TransportWithMessageCredential  is not providing complete end-to-end security. Because of this my confusion started. I want My client to send message and it is encrypted at  soap message level and Server message to Client  should be encrypted at Message level.

Comment: TransportWithMessageCredential is complete end-to-end encryption ... it's fully Transport (SSL), but the client auth credentials are buried within the message body for cases where load balancers/reverse proxies are used.